fping gets return packet when run from terminal, a script, but not when the script is called by transmission-daemon
I'm using the following ..
fping -c1 computer
I get 0% packet loss when I run it manually from the terminal.  I get 0% packet loss when I run it from a script, ~/scripts/torrent.done.script.
But I get 100% packet loss when transmission-daemon triggers, and runs the script.
computer : xmt/rcv/%loss = 1/0/100%

I'm at a loss trying to figure this out.  I tried specifying the IP address explicitly, I tried using only IPv4 but same results. I tried with a public IP address, same results.  It tried with a VPN and without, same results.
ping works, fping does not.  So bizarre, to me.

What happens if you do other network-related commands (e.g., curl, scp or wget) from those contexts?

I just tried ping and it worked!  So weird.

is transmission-daemon perhaps running as a different user, in a different network namespace, or in a different cgroups scope or such?

@MarcusMüller ping works fping does not.  Same network, same user.

@slowcoder not what I asked.

Is ping not a network-related command?
